# Difficulty with icelandic characters in bibliography/apacite

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, unicode

I have a problem with getting my icelandic characters to show up when I compile. I´m using texstudio and I used jabref for being the reference manager and I´m using apacite for the citing "system" Everything seems to good except my icelandic characters do not show up, I get errors in everything I try to do. Ive tried using just plain bibtex, I´ve tried biblatex and I just get more and more errors... anyways here´s my code in full, it´s not long.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % Default font size is 12pt, it can be changed here


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{apacite}

\geometry{a4paper} % Set the page size to be A4 as opposed to the default US Letter
\usepackage{float} % Allows putting an [H] in \begin{figure} to specify the exact location of the figure
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images such as the example fish picture
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\linespread{1.2} % Line spacing

%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Uncomment to remove all indentation from paragraphs

\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.9}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.9}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.1}
\begin{document}


\section{Results} % Sub-section
%------------------------------------------------


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{heimildir2}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

the errors I get with this are the following.

```
line 21: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�s not set up for use with LaTeX stadall, IST EN 12464-1:2011}}}

: No suitable language definition file (icelandic.apc) found.
line 120: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Heres what heimildir2.bib looks like

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.9.2.
% Encoding: Cp1252

@BOOK{lysingartaekni,
  title = {Kennslubók i Lýsingartækni},
  publisher = {IÐNÚ},
  year = {2006},
  author = {Leif Wall},
  owner = {Axel Sig},
  timestamp = {2014.02.02}
}

@ARTICLE{journal1,
  author = {WJM van Bommel Professor lr, GJ van den Beld lr},
  title = {Lighting for work: a review of visual and biological effects},
  journal = {Lighting research and technology},
  year = {2004},
  volume = {36,4},
  pages = {255-269},
  owner = {Axel Sig},
  timestamp = {2014.02.02}
}

@comment{jabref-meta: fileDirectory:C:\\Users\\Axel Sig\\Dropbox\\2man
na möppur\\Andri, Axel, Orri\\Aðferðarfræði\\Skýrsla;}

@comment{jabref-meta: pdfDirectory:C:\\Users\\Axel Sig\\Dropbox\\2mann
a möppur\\Andri, Axel, Orri\\Aðferðarfræði\\Skýrsla;}
```

and there´s more to come.

Comment: What does `heimildir2.bib` look like?

Comment: Have you tried using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `biblatex` with `biber`?

Comment: I am using \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and I´m currently using bibtex but I also tried using biblatex but biber I´m not familiar with, must look that up. Also I edited my post with what heimildir2.bib looks like at the moment but there are more books to be put there.

Comment: You have to tell JabRef to export the database as UTF-8, not cp2512

Comment: bibtex is notoriously tiresome with 8bit chars (it can't sort them, mostly).  i've read an assertion (in biber docs) that it simply doesn't work with utf-8.  if remotely possible, i would recommend switching to biber for this job.  (i appreciate you've a fair bit to do anyway, but i suspect getting _au fait_ with the biber/biblatex setup would repay the effort involved.)

Comment: Thank you, my problem was that I thought I had allready set jabref to utf8 but the thing is that It looks like if you start a new document/database while set in cp2512 and change it to utf8 it doesn´t change really. I made a new document while the setting was to utf8 and now it compiles great. Thank you everyone that commented.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a JabRef configuration issue solved by the OP.